Laravel Artisan::call('migrate --seed --force') Not Executing Fully When Initializing in Controller
I'm using Artisan::call('migrate --seed --force') in my Laravel controller to run database migrations and seed the database. However, this command does not seem to execute fully, causing the script to hang. The other Artisan commands before it work as expected.
   try {
            \Log::debug("message Starting to clear config and cache.");
            Artisan::call('config:clear');
            Artisan::call('cache:clear');

            \Log::debug('Saving database environment variables.');
            $results = $this->environmentManager->saveDatabaseVariables($request);

            if (array_key_exists('success', $results)) {
                // \Log::debug('Generating app key and optimizing the application.'. json_encode( $results));
                \Log::debug('Generating app key and optimizing the application.');
                Artisan::call('key:generate --force');
                Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
                \Log::debug('config.');
                Artisan::call('config:clear');
                Artisan::call('cache:clear');
                \Log::debug('storage.');
                Artisan::call('storage:link');

                \Log::debug('Running database migrations and seeding.' );
                   $output =  Artisan::call('migrate --seed --force');
                   \Log::debug('migration'.  $output);
            }

            \Log::debug('Process completed successfully.');
            return response()->json("tes ok", 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::debug('An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['error' => 'An error occurred while processing the request.'], 500);
        }

What I have tried:
Running php php artisan migrate --seed --force  from the command line works as expected.
Added logging before and after the command to check where it hangs, confirming it's the migrate command.
Tried breaking down the Artisan commands into smaller steps.
Expected behavior:
The Artisan::call('migrate --seed --force') command should execute fully, running all migrations and seeding the database without causing the script to hang.
No errors are logged, and the script just hangs indefinitely.
Other Artisan commands work fine within the same controller method.

I am totally curious why are you executing all of this. You are even running key:generate

I wanted to configure the app using API when the user  install it  for the  first time

migrate should not be running all migrations. Only migrations that have not ran yet. I think we're missing critical context here, is this meant to be used to initialise a new tenant in a multi-tenant application?

@apokryfos yes it need to run that didn't run but it's not running fully when initialize it
